# Any method of pausing Screen Recording in Quicktime is not working

Tags: video, quicktime

I have mac Catalina 10.15.6.  It runs QuickTime version 10.5

I am aware of this post.  Nothing in this works for me, and the post is rather old:
[Pause screen recording in QuickTime X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14664/pause-screen-recording-in-quicktime-x)

No suggested combination of hovering over the stop bar, hitting escape, pressing the option key, pressing the space bar - none of that works.

Is there a difference between QuickTime and QuickTime X maybe? It looks like QuickTime X is just the packaged QuickTime ever since Mac OSX came out.  Needless to say this is frustrating because the instructions are clear.  BTW in pressing those keys all I get is the Mac native "thunk" or I guess "oops" sound.